# Script to help with edge loop deletion

Tags: python, scripting, edges, loop

I'm not new to Blender but I am new to the scripting aspect, so this isn't something I can throw together yet.. But I need this functionality to speed up my workflow. I would like to ask if the process outlined below is possible to script.

loop through all objects and do the following to each:

1. In edit mode, select a single edge at the end of the "cylinder" (doesn't matter which side)
   [image: edge to select]
2. Select edge rings
   [image: edge rings]
3. Checker de-select
   [image: checker deselect]
4. Select Edge Loops
   [image]
5. Delete Edge Loops

I think the first part is probably the hardest.. it needs to "find" and select an edge in the end loop. I would like to learn scripting so I plan to build off of this one here. Help in building this script would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I came up with:

```
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT') 
bpy.ops.mesh.select_mode(type="VERT")
bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action = 'DESELECT')
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT')
obj.data.vertices[0].select = True
obj.data.vertices[1].select = True
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT')
bpy.ops.mesh.select_mode(type="EDGE")

#bpy.ops.mesh.edgering_select
bpy.ops.mesh.loop_multi_select(ring=True)

bpy.ops.mesh.select_nth(nth=1, skip=1)

bpy.ops.mesh.loop_multi_select(ring=False)

bpy.ops.mesh.delete_edgeloop()
```

It isnt very clean or "Pythonic" so any suggestions would still be appreciated!